# how to communicate php5-fpm by netcat?

Tags: php, sockets, unix, netcat

I want to understand how to fast-cgi unix sockets working, so i try to connect php5-fpm like:

```
sudo nc -U /var/run/php5-fpm.sock // it's working with nginx
```

i sent some raw php code, but socket reponses nothing. How can I use it with netcat? if i can't use netcat with this unix socket file, can you give me an example in python, java, .. etc. How can I implement fast cgi sockets like nginx? I really try to find documentation on this area but i didn't find really usefull things. I looked php-fpm source code but its a bit complicated. Thanks for your answers.